# Is it possible to generate UUID v1 with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, uuid

I read JMeter's manual and saw that there is __uuid() function for JMeter. It allows to generate UUID type 4 for JMeter tests. Is it possible to generate UUIDv1 in JMeter or maybe some plugin exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend taking the following steps:

1. Download [Jug library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome) (for example from [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/uuid/java-uuid-generator/)) and drop the .jar somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Once done you should be able to generate UUIDv1 using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) like:

   ```
   import com.fasterxml.uuid.EthernetAddress
   import com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators
   import com.fasterxml.uuid.impl.TimeBasedGenerator

   def addr = EthernetAddress.fromInterface()
   def gen = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(addr)
   def v1uuid = gen.generate()

   log.info(v1uuid.toString())
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Generate UUIDv1]

References:

- [Generating version 1 UUIDs](http://mediashelf.github.io/uuid-datepath-idmapper/generate_uuids.html)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 1):

In jmeter you can add JSR 223 Sampler choose Java language and execute java code for UUID version 1:

```
 String timeuuid = com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.timeBased().toString();
```

And then add it to Jmeter variable:

```
 vars.put("myUUID", timeuuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll generate the 64 least and most significant bits as long values:

```
private static long get64LeastSignificantBitsForVersion1() {
    Random random = new Random();
    long random63BitLong = random.nextLong() & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
    long variant3BitFlag = 0x8000000000000000L;
    return random63BitLong + variant3BitFlag;
}
 
private static long get64MostSignificantBitsForVersion1() {
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(1582, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, LocalDateTime.now());
    long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
    long nanos = duration.getNano();
    long timeForUuidIn100Nanos = seconds * 10000000 + nanos * 100;
    long least12SignificatBitOfTime = (timeForUuidIn100Nanos & 0x000000000000FFFFL) >> 4;
    long version = 1 << 12;
    return 
      (timeForUuidIn100Nanos & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF0000L) + version + least12SignificatBitOfTime;
}
```

We can then pass these two values to the constructor of the UUID:

```
public static UUID generateType1UUID() {
 
    long most64SigBits = get64MostSignificantBitsForVersion1();
    long least64SigBits = get64LeastSignificantBitsForVersion1();
 
    return new UUID(most64SigBits, least64SigBits);
}
```